# Searching Word document from add-in

Tags: ms-word, word-addins

I'm finding a text that has certain style in the Word document. I know it can be done using Selection.Find but I can't find any other way how to do it.

The issue with Selection.Find is that progress of add-in is visible to the user because if something is found, it's selected, etc. Is there a way how to do it so the text isn't selected ?

Thank you

Comment: `range.Next(WdUnits.wdCharacterFormatting)` can be used to loop over the different styles, but it has few small issues. I can post sample code in C# if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Range` to search can be stored in a variable and use `range.Find` instead of `Selection.Find`:

```
Range range = document.Content

if ( range.Find.Execute("*") ) 
{
    Debug.Print(range.Text);
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, it works fine :-) (I'd upvote but I don't have enough reputation.)